# dataframes classes from Rpy2 to pandas and back

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I have a daframe in `rpy2` that ouputs the following classes:

```
In [58]: [tuple(x.rclass) for x in df_rpy2]
Out[58]: [('integer',), ('integer',), ('numeric',), ('numeric',)]
```

Now if I do :

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri as pd2ri

tmp = pd2ri.ri2py(df_rpy2)
df_from_pd = pd2ri.py2ri(tmp)
print([tuple(x.rclass) for x in df_from_pd])
```

I get `[('array',), ('array',), ('array',), ('array',)]`

How can still have the initial classes ?